Issues with importing and using Clap.with_name() function
Have been enjoying learning Rust by reading and going through the examples in Rust in Action…
However, one program isn’t working as listed in the book (and can’t find it on the book’s Github repo).
So, the author is showing the reader how to build a command line utility, using a crate called clap, which will serve as a mini grep-like tool in Rust.
Rust version on macOS:
rustc --version
rustc 1.81.0 (eeb90cda1 2024-09-04)


Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "grep-lite"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
clap = "4.5.17"
regex = "1"


main.rs:
use regex::Regex;
use clap::{App,Arg};

fn main() {

    let args = App::new("grep-lite")
                  .version("0.1")
                  .about("searches for patterns")
                  .arg(Arg::with_name("pattern")
                          .help("The pattern to search for")
                          .takes_value(true)
                          .required(true)      
                  ).get_matches();

    let pattern = args.value_of("pattern").unwrap();              

    let re = Regex::new(pattern).unwrap();

    let quote = "Every face, every shop, bedroom window, public-house, and
  dark square is a picture feverishly turned--in search of what?
  It is the same with books. What do we seek through millions of pages?";
   
    for line in quote.lines() {
      let contains_substring = re.find(line); 
      match contains_substring {
            Some(_) => println!("{}", line),
            None => (),
      }
    }
  }

After invoking cargo run:
cargo run
   Compiling grep-lite v0.1.0 (/Users/pnwlover/RustInAction/ch2/grep-lite)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `clap::App`
 --> src/main.rs:2:12
  |
2 | use clap::{App,Arg};
  |            ^^^ no `App` in the root

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `with_name` found for struct `Arg` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:9:29
    |
9   |                   .arg(Arg::with_name("pattern")
    |                             ^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `Arg`
    |
note: if you're trying to build a new `Arg`, consider using `Arg::new` which returns `Arg`
   --> /Users/pnwlover/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/clap_builder-4.5.17/src/builder/arg.rs:114:5
    |
114 |     pub fn new(id: impl Into<Id>) -> Self {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0432, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `grep-lite` (bin "grep-lite") due to 2 previous errors

Rust rocks but do wish to understand what I am doing wrong?

clap::App had been depracated in clap 3.x, and you are using clap 4.x. See clap's docs for a migration guide.

Okay, thanks, got it working with the code by downgrading to clap 2 in Cargo.toml.

That's not what you are supposed to do. You should stay on the latest version, and update your code for it.

@ChayimFriedman - True, but I am just trying to get through understanding the code in the book I listed by following along.
